# express.js res.redirect in app.post route not redirecting to given URL

Tags: php, node.js

I'm using express.js and app.post route is used to validate user and redirect valid user to PHP page using the res.redirect(), but instead of redirecting it is displaying **Found. Redirecting to http://localhost/home.php**

my server.js code is as follows:

```
app.post('/set_node_session', function(req, res){
    sess = req.session; 

    var usermail = req.body.field1;
    var password = req.body.field2;

    var sql="SELECT * FROM userInfo WHERE userEmail='"+usermail+"'";    
    con.query(sql, function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;     
        sess.user_id=result[0].userId;
        sess.first_name=result[0].userFname;
        sess.last_name=result[0].userLname;

        if(sess.user_id) {
            res.redirect('http://localhost/home.php');
        }
        else {
            res.redirect('http://localhost/login.php');
        }
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nodejs:

```js
var resp = sess.user_id ? '1' : '0';
res.send(resp );
```

and in your php:

```js
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if(result == 1){
    header("Location: http://localhost/home.php");
}
else{
    header("Location: http://localhost/login.php");
}
die();
```

Comment: It doesn't works .it gives output: Found. Redirecting to http://localhost/home.php

Comment: are you doing it with ajax?

Comment: we are not using Ajax,we are posting form from php page as follows:


$url = 'http://localhost:3000/set_node_session';
  
  $fields = array(
     'field1' => $_SESSION["user_email"],
     'field2' => $_SESSION["user_pwd"],
  );
  
  $postvars = http_build_query($fields);
  
  $ch = curl_init();

  
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);

  
  $result = curl_exec($ch);

Comment: well that`s your problem you cant redirect from the node js because your "client" is the php and not the browser . you need to send 0 or 1 to the php and then do the redirect from the php as it is the direct connection to the user browser.  also i don`t think the req.session will work as you are not sending any cookies from the  php. also you can`t set any cookies from the node js from the same reason .  ill edit my answer